# How do you get the name of SignedInGamers on WP7 with XNA?

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to get the SignedInGamers name on WP7 like you do with the XBOX? I've tried testing it with:

SignedInGamer gamer = Gamer.SignedInGamers[0];
gamer.DisplayName;

But have only received a null value for the gamer object on the phone.

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GamerServices` namespace (where this functionality lives) is only available to XBox-Live games. As such it's not available to everyone creating games.

You must have the elevated API access granted to MS partners allowed to create games which interact with Live to be able to use this functionality.

I'm assuming that you aren't a game studio with these extra priviliges and that is why you're not getting nulls returned for these objects.